# EF Core throws System.InvalidOperationException: "Sequence contains no matching elements"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have encountered a weird problem with EF core when translating LINQ expressions to SQL. Occasionally (only when the web application has just been started ie. using `dotnet run` command, however not always) I get `System.InvalidOperationException`, stating: `Sequence contains no matching elements`. Exception is thrown in this part of code:

```
var results = await qry
    .AsNoTracking()
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here, variable `qry` is of type `IQueryable` (ie. `IQueryable<Street>`).
I tried debugging, and in the `DebugView`, both `DbContext` and `DbSet<Street>` are not null nor disposed, and it is stated that the variable `qry` should be translated as follows:

```
"DbSet<Street>()
     .Include(p => p.LocalBoard)
         .ThenInclude(p => p.City)
     .Where(prop => prop.Name.ToLower().Contains(string.IsNullOrEmpty(<>c__DisplayClass1_0.filter.Name) ? prop.Name.ToLower() : <>c__DisplayClass1_0.filter.Name.ToLower()) 
         && prop.LocalBoardID == <>c__DisplayClass1_0.filter.LocalBoardID != null ? <>c__DisplayClass1_0.filter.LocalBoardID.Value : prop.LocalBoardID
     )
     .Where(r => r.DeleteDate == null)
     .Select(r => r)
     .OrderBy(p => p.Name)"
```

Since I am not using neither `.Single()` nor `.First()` (nor awaiting their `async` equivalents), I'm not sure what is causing this exception. I do have to mention that the given exception is very hard to recreate, since it occurs irregularly (only when starting the application, however not always).

Does anyone know what could cause that exception? I am using .NET 7.0 and EF Core v7.0.11.

**Edit:**
full `qry` value:

```
var qry = context.Street
    .Include(p => p.LocalBoard)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.City)     
    .Where(prop => prop.Name.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Name) ? prop.Name.ToLower() : filter.Name.ToLower())
        && prop.LocalBoardID == (filter.LocalBoardID != null ? filter.LocalBoardID.Value : prop.LocalBoardID)
    )
    .Where(r => r.DeleteDate == null)
    .Select(r => r)     
    .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Full exception stack trace:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Sequence contains no matching element'
at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoMatchException()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression..ctor(IEntityType entityType, ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionFactory.Select(IEntityType entityType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.CreateShapedQueryExpression(IEntityType entityType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
at MyProject_api.Domain.Services.ApiLogic.Sequential.MSSQL.ActiveDatabase.Core.RServiceCore`3.<GetAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in E:\Goran\Development\MyProject\MyProject-api\Domain\Services\ApiLogic\Sequential\MSSQL\ActiveDatabase\Core\RServiceCore.cs:line 194
```

**Edit 2:**
`Street` class definition:

```
[Table("Street")]
public class Street
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(124)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LocalBoardID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocalBoardID")]
    public virtual LocalBoard LocalBoard { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }


    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

`LocalBoard` class definition:

```
[Table("LocalBoard")]
public class LocalBoard
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CityID")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }


    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}
```

`City` class definition:

```
[Table("City")]
public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
    

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<LocalBoard> LocalBoards { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your query and exception stack trace.

Comment: My guess is you actually hit the database, something is then wrong with data. If you are using MsSql server try to start a profiler. Then try to run the query yourself and see if there are unexpected data in the result.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle I'm not sure whether it would be a database issue, since it occurs on restarting web api (whether database server is restarted or not). But I will try to find more information in profiler

Comment: Looking at EF Core source code. Something wrong with mapping. Maybe your properties do not have setters? Show your classes.

Comment: Also show other entities, `LocalBoard` and `City`.

Comment: Looks good. Can you try to remove `.Select(r => r)`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have tried removing `.Select(r => r)` before posting my question, but unfortunately it didn't have any impact

Comment: Try to simplify query by removing operators one by one. To understand which entity has problem.